# Генератор страниц

Tags: php, javascript, html5, golang

Есть довольно много различных сайтов по генерации страниц, лендингов. К пример platformalp или lpgenerator.

Хотелось бы узнать - как именно происходит построение страницы и её хранение (хранится ли полная html со своими "стилями" с помощью которых можно выделять и редактировать объекты на странице, или это граф/дерево элементов).

Может кто подскажет какой-нить open source проект, чтобы можно было посмотреть на работу изнутри

Comment: говнокод на большинстве получается, все объекты в позиции абсолют

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю надо копать в сторону хранения сериализованых объектов и перегрузки методов возвращения данных.

Если, например, в архитектуре лендинга есть три изменяемых элемента, которые требуется хранить в базе данных, то я бы связал доменное имя, идентификатор клиента и изменяемые элементы.

Например у каждого клиента есть условные данные в базе, которые определены в условном классе. Этот класс можно расширить наследованием базового класса, который  влияет на представление. Представление может меняться перегрузкой информации базового класса условным классом.

Формы и другие взаимодействия могут добавляться модульно.

Стили, скрипт и контент можно обрабатывать и хранить на дисках. Выдавать внешний вид можно сериализацией. Верстка, которая используется на лендингах не похоже на верстку ручной работы. Значит надо смотреть топовые визуальные редакторы и их движки.

Чтобы реализовать такой проект требуется серьезный подход архитектора.

В моем примере типы данных я назвал классами для упрощения темы.